# Facebook App redirecting to https

Tags: facebook

My facebook application is redirecting to https can somebody help me i dont have ssl on my server and i want to keep the app on http, with https it generate the following error

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

Comment: can we have more details such as is your canvas url working fine if opened seperately from facebook. As well as did you gave secure canvas url in your facebook app setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an article that gives a good run down on this, [Hyper Arts Blog](http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/facebook-secure-browsing-https-iframe-tabs-mixed-content-warnings/).

It appears that facebook is going to encourage secure browsing and the only way to avoid end user warnings is to set yourself up with a secure site.

Answer (score 0):

You have setup your facebook app to have a secure canvas.  Try removing it.

Also, your own personal facebook settings probably have https usage enabled... https://www.facebook.com/blog.php?post=486790652130... Try unchecking that settings.

If you don't provide a secure canvas the user's (who has requested facebook use https when possible) browsers is supposed to ask the user if they can go to the unsecured site... but we are talking facebook here so expect the unexpected.

Comment: This message is out of date now. All Facebook apps must now supply a secure canvas url, or may be forced to run in sandbox mode only.